# Using "involve" for an application and a user

Tags: phrase-usage

Can I say

> For the applications that involve a user, such as enhancing the page readability, content extraction is better served with the aid of the user through a visual tool, rather than an inflexible automatic method.

To mean the applications that provide something for a user and a user works with them.

---

**Update**, I came up with "*the tasks that involve user interaction*"

Comment: What sort of application does not involve a user?

Comment: @StoneyB maybe I should say **tasks**, for example a tool may summarize a web page to ease the search for a search engine. but a tool that facilitate reading a webpage is something that is provided for the user.

Comment: @StoneyB also, by application I mean applications of something, applications of Web content extraction.

Comment: @Ahmad What is the problem of **involving** ?

Comment: @Cardinal nothing, just I didn't find any result for it in google. Then I was doubtful.

Comment: @Ahmad Is there any necessity to say "...**a** user..." ?

Comment: @Cardinal no, whatever is better.

Comment: @Cardinal I came up with *involve user interaction*

Comment: What about "for user interactive applications"

Comment: Some tasks, such as enhancing page readability, are more readily done by the user with a visual tool than by an inflexible automatic method.  You are juggling too many subject phrases and modifiers:  applications ... enhancing readability...content extraction....that involve a user...with the aid of the user..   You don't have to cram everything into one sentence.

Comment: @Cardinal Thank you but I prefer, *involve user interaction* to emphasize the difference.

Comment: @TRomano I agree, I tried to paraphrase a sentence but now I used almost the original one, which is: *However, for some applications that involve user interaction, content extraction is better served by direct and visual wrapper construction rather than unsupervised wrapper induction.*

Comment: @TRomano is it better now? I may use your suggestion too.

Comment: *Wrapper induction* is a highly technical term. If the reader knows what wrapper induction means, the reader doesn't have to be told that some tasks are better performed by the user with a visual tool than by an automated process.  It's rather like explaining fractals to Benoit Mandelbrot.

Comment: @TRomano according to your suggestion I must write, *However, some applications that involve user interaction are more readily done by a visual tool rather than an inflexible automatic method*, by the way, the sentence I borrowed is *For the average web user, web content extraction is better served by direct and visual wrapper construction rather than unsupervised wrapper induction.*

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "borrowed". I would not say "must write". I was trying to pare your sentence down to its core idea, because it had a number of extra phrases that were not making it any clearer.

Comment: @TRomano Sure, certainly I will write something that is both succinct (with help of your suggestion) and technical to include main points. by **borrowed** I mean I saw the sentence somewhere.